# why error shows "/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:932" while start using chatterbot training ai.yml?

Tags: python, c++, chatterbot

i try to execute the example code from chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
                                                       
chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')

# Create a new trainer for the chatbot
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Train the chatbot based on the english corpus
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

# Get a response to an input statement
chatbot.get_response("Hello, how are you today?")
```

it shows errors as follows:

```
Training ai.yml: [#######             ] 34%/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:932: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = __pyx_t_5spacy_6syntax_6_state_StateC*; _Alloc = std::allocator<__pyx_t_5spacy_6syntax_6_state_StateC*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = __pyx_t_5spacy_6syntax_6_state_StateC*&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__builtin_expect(__n < this->size(), true)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

i'm so confusing and don't know how to deal with it.any help would be appreciated

Comment: You seem to have [copied their sample program correctly](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot#user-content-basic-usage).  There is a bug elsewhere.

Comment: There's a bug somewhere in the compiled C++ code that results in a crash. An experienced C++ developer will need to debug, analyze, determine the reason for the crash, and fix it.